# What causes an IBM MQ Topic Subscription destination error

Tags: java, ibm-mq, message-driven-bean, jms-topic

Getting the following error.

This is on a system where two IBM WAS Application servers have an MDB that subscribe to the same MQ Topic.

```
[4/18/22 11:01:55:843 PDT] 00000351 SibMessage    W   [:] CWSJY0003W: MQJCA4018: MessageEndpoint afterDelivery() call failed with: 'afterDelivery failure'.
[4/18/22 11:01:55:839 PDT] 00000351 SibMessage    W   [:] CWSJY0003W: MQJCA4004: Message delivery to an MDB 'xxxListenerMDB($Proxy@9f96fx)' failed with exception: 'JMSCC0110: An exception 'com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedInvalidDestinationException: JMSWMQ0026: Failed to subscribe to topic 'SYSTEM.MANAGED.NDURABLE.DB5F92523C959805' using MQSUB.
There may have been a problem creating the subscription due to it being used by another message consumer.
Make sure any message consumers using this subscription are closed before trying to create a new subscription under the same name. Please see the linked exception for more information.' was caught while processing a message for delivery to a message driven bean.'.
[4/18/22 11:01:55:837 PDT] 00000351 SibMessage    W   [:] CWSJY0003W: JMSCC0110: An exception '
                       Message : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedInvalidDestinationException: JMSWMQ0026: Failed to subscribe to topic 'SYSTEM.MANAGED.NDURABLE.DB5F92523C959887' using MQSUB.
There may have been a problem creating the subscription due to it being used by another message consumer.
Make sure any message consumers using this subscription are closed before trying to create a new subscription under the same name. Please see the linked exception for more information.
                         Class : class com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedInvalidDestinationException
                         Stack : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:498)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:216)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageConsumer.java:124)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConsumerShadow.initialize(WMQConsumerShadow.java:920)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSyncConsumerShadow.initialize(WMQSyncConsumerShadow.java:135)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSession.loadMessageReference(WMQSession.java:1386)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.consume(JmsSessionImpl.java:3283)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.run(JmsSessionImpl.java:2905)
                               : com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession.run(MQSession.java:958)
                               : com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.ASFWorkImpl.doDelivery(ASFWorkImpl.java:111)
                               : com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.AbstractWorkImpl.run(AbstractWorkImpl.java:238)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.j2c.work.WorkProxy.run(WorkProxy.java:669)
                               : com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
     Caused by [1] --> Message : com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2428' ('MQRC_NO_SUBSCRIPTION').
                         Class : class com.ibm.mq.MQException
                         Stack : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:204)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageConsumer.java:124)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConsumerShadow.initialize(WMQConsumerShadow.java:920)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSyncConsumerShadow.initialize(WMQSyncConsumerShadow.java:135)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSession.loadMessageReference(WMQSession.java:1386)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.consume(JmsSessionImpl.java:3283)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.run(JmsSessionImpl.java:2905)
                               : com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession.run(MQSession.java:958)
                               : com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.ASFWorkImpl.doDelivery(ASFWorkImpl.java:111)
                               : com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.AbstractWorkImpl.run(AbstractWorkImpl.java:238)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.j2c.work.WorkProxy.run(WorkProxy.java:669)
                               : com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
' was caught while processing a message for delivery to a message driven bean.
```

Any help on this is GREATLY APPRECIATED!

Comment: Normally `SYSTEM.MANAGED.NDURABLE.DB5F92523C959887` would be the name of a managed queue subscribed to a topic, not the name of a topic itself.   If you want two MDBs to receive copies of all messages published you need to be sure the client ID is different.   If you want them to share the punished messages then you need to use a JMS shared subscription or a cloned subscription.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @JoshMc. The full scenario is that there are 2 servers each running an instance of the application. When something is published to the topic, the MDB on each server (of which there can be multiple MDBs running at a time) needs to pick up the message and send to the application. In the past we used the jms DMLC to subscribe to the topic, but we just converted to use MDBs. So the Topic settings have not changed, but we do have a new Application Specification set up for the MDB. Could this be configured incorrectly? Also, the warnings are only on ONE of the servers :(

Comment: one more note, the topic is also non-durable. if that helps.

Comment: What are the settings.   Do they have the same client id configured?

Comment: The client id on the application specification is blank, which we thought was correct. And it appears to work until some condition triggers the error message to start appearing in the logs. Maybe a certain load triggers it? I can't make sense of it. The message started appearing this morning on one server, and then a few hours later the same message started appearing on the 2nd server. Thank you!